# lambda capture in C++17

Tags: c++, lambda, c++17, language-lawyer, language-design

[[expr.prim.lambda.capture]/7](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.lambda.capture#7):

> If an expression potentially references a local entity within a scope in which it is odr-usable, and the expression would be potentially evaluated if the effect of any enclosing typeid expressions ([expr.typeid]) were ignored, the entity is said to be implicitly captured by each intervening lambda-expression with an associated capture-default that does not explicitly capture it. The implicit capture of *this is deprecated when the capture-default is =; see [depr.capture.this]. [Example 4:

```
void f(int, const int (&)[2] = {});
void test() {
  const int x = 17;
  auto g = [](auto a) {
    f(x);                       // OK, calls #1, does not capture x
  };

  auto g1 = [=](auto a) {
    f(x);                       // OK, calls #1, captures x
  };
}
```

> ... Within g1, an implementation can optimize away the capture of x as it is not odr-used. — end example]

So an entity is captured even if it is not odr-used by the lambda body, and the example below says that the implementations can optimize it away. **Therefore, since the implementations can optimize it away, why add such a rule? What's the point of it?**

[cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda#Lambda_capture) says it was added in C++17. **What's the original proposal?**

Comment: `int x = 0; [&] { [&] { [=] { f(x); } } }` - `x` is used here... it has to be captured by the interwening lambdas too, due to how scoping works with captures. Just like the text you quoted mentions.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica But the innermost lambda still has access to `x`.

Comment: What do you mean "but"? Yes, it uses `x`. That's the reason the ones between it and the actual scope of `x` need to capture it.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica What I'm asking is about lambda's non-odr-usage of an entity with automatic storage duration, and your `x` is not constant, so odr-use.

Comment: How do you surmise an entity is not odr-used from that paragraph?

Comment: If you feel you can better delineate all the potential cases, thus *reliably* say when a capture shouldn't happen, I'm sure it will be a much appreciated proposal.

Comment: That's an example, which is a) not normative, only informative b) exercises the infamous as-if rule.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica The standard already says that `x` in `g1` is not odr-used, I think it's clear enough.

Comment: And again, that's not part of the ***normative*** text. How should the normative text express it?

Comment: IMO this is a DR which should be applied retroactively to C++11 (except for the portions for structured binding, which can be only applied to C++17).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[P0588R0](https://wg21.link/P0588R0) contains the rationale explaining why the rules for implicit capture were changed in order to capture some variables that are not going to be odr-used anyway. It's very subtle.

Basically, in order to determine the size of a lambda closure type, you need to know which variables are captured and which ones are not, but under the old rules:

- in order to determine whether a variable is captured implicitly, you have to know whether it's odr-used, and
- in order to know whether the variable is odr-used, you have to perform substitution into the lambda's body, and
- if the function call operator is generic, it means the above substitution is done at a point where the function call operator itself is not ready to be instantiated yet (since its own template parameters aren't yet known). This causes problems that could be avoided by not doing the substitution in the first place.

The paper gives the following example:

```
template<typename T> void f(T t) {
    auto lambda = [&](auto a) {
        if constexpr (Copyable<T>() && sizeof(a) == 32) {
            T u = t;
        } else {
            // ... do not use t ...
        }
    };
    // ...
}
```

When `f` is instantiated with a non-copyable type, ideally we would like the branch with `T u = t;` to be discarded. That's what the `if constexpr` is there for. But an `if constexpr` statement does not discard the un-taken branch until the point at which the condition is no longer dependent---meaning that the type of `a` must be known before `T u = t;` can be discarded. Unfortunately, under the old rules, `T` must be substituted into `T u = t;` in order to determine whether `t` is captured, and this happens before any opportunity to discard this statement

The new rules simply declare that `t` is captured; therefore, the compiler doesn't have to perform any substitution into the lambda body until the point at which a specialization of the function call operator is referenced (and thus, its body can be fully instantiated). And if the compiler is somehow able to prove that `t` will never be odr-used by any possible specialization of the function call operator, it's free to optimize it out.

Comment: Why it captures an entity implicitly if the entity is named in a potentially-evaluated expression within an expression that does not depend on a generic lambda parameter?

Comment: @Blackteahamburger The paper explains: "Note that we propose applying this treatment uniformly to both generic and non-generic lambdas (this is not essential to the proposal, but seems to give a more consistent language rule)."

Comment: What is this consistency for? Is it good that the choice of capturing or not is left to implementations?

Comment: @Blackteahamburger The implementation is required to behave as if the variable is captured, even if it can tell that it won't be odr-used. Therefore, the implementation can only optimize out a value capture if there are no side effects of copying the original variable to the class member. This improves consistency in that, under the old rules, it can sometimes be a real head-scratcher to determine whether the variable gets captured.

Comment: This does ease the workload for some language-lawyers, but the impact on the average developers is redundant captures...

Comment: The rules can even only apply to expressions in constexpr-if, and the condition of it depends on a generic lambda parameter.

Comment: @Blackteahamburger The comments section should be used to ask for clarification on answers, not to complain about the standard.

Comment: Well I'll discuss it elsewhere.